# Changing fonts in main title of plot in R

Tags: r, plot, sweave, tikz, tikzdevice

I am using Sweave and knitr together with `<<dev="tikz">>=` for figures. For simplicity, I first will try to explain my problem without providing a minimal working example:

I am using the command `acf` for plotting an autocorrelation function and want to change the font of the main title to e.g. `font.main=1`. I looked up the documentation which tells me that additional arguments of `acf` are the same as for `plot.acf`, which in turn uses the same as `plot`. Therefore I think `font.main` should work for `acf` as good as it does for `plot`. Unfortunately, adding an additional parameter for `font.main` in `acf` has no effect on the font of the main title. However, in `plot` this works fine. What is wrong here?

Comment: Tyr: `par(font.main=1)` before running the `acf` command.

Comment: This works. But why is it wrong to put it into the `acf` command?

Comment: adding `cex.lab=1.5` works, as does `font.axis` and `font.lab`, but not `font.main`. It's a mystery.

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to set cex and cex.main, cex.sub...  the par() solution works, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something seems odd because the documentation of `acf` states that `...` are "further arguments to be passed to `plot.acf`". And, the documentation of `plot.acf` further states that `...` are "graphics parameters to be passed to the plotting routines".

This seems partially correct as passing `font.lab` and `font.axis` appear to produce the intended effect. However, `font.main` is ignored for reasons yet to be uncovered.

Until this gets fixed, the solution is to change the graphical parameters first, then run the command.

```
op <- par(font.main=1, ...)
acf(...)
par(op) # change back
```

Comment: Ok, but why does the documentation of `acf` says that arguments for `plot` can also be used as arguments for `acf`? Isn't this misleading?